# BEM - How to add a condition to a modifier?

Tags: bem

I have positioning modifiers for my project's images. One of them is **`.image_stuck_left`**.
In the layout there is an image that should stick to the left *only* on wide screens.
How should I add this condition to the existing modifier?
Is `image_stuck_left_viewport_wide` a good name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independent blocks should not know about positioning. Consider using [mixes](https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes) instead.

For you case it'd be something like this. Let's have a block called `some-section` where images should stuck to the left. In this case you may mix universal `image` block with an element of `some-section`: `<img class="image some-section__image">` and apply styles about positioning to `.some-section__image`.

As for wide viewport just use media queries for `.some-section__image`. No need for additional classes in this case.

PS: `image_stuck_left_viewport_wide` is not a valid naming according to https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/

Answer (score 2):

Why would an image stick to left only on widescreen?

This doesn't seems to be a responsibility for the image only, but a responsibility for the layout, certainly its parent block.

Considering the following HTML:

```html
<div class="page">
  <img class="image image--stuck-to-left-on-wide-screen" />
  <div class"page__content">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would create what I call a *nest*, it just an element made to welcome a child block. A nest is a great way to decide the size and position of a child block.

So I would write:

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class"page__image">
    <img class="image" />
  </div>
  <div class"page__content">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now, the element `page__image` could define all the logic we need for the position. For example "stuck to the left on wide screen":

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .page__image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

I'm not a fan of BEM mixes. The concept is really near of what I call "nest", but:

1. A nest is not a new concept, it's just a normal element
2. A mix breaks the isolation between two components.